# A video encoding technique

Tags: python-2.7, video-streaming, video-processing, video-encoding

i am trying to create an erasure coding-based technique for video streaming over VANET, i managed to stream a video from the cam and encode it, now i want to apply the XOR operation on two successive frames and send the three all in one array (by three i mean each frame and its successive one and the XOR operation resulting frame).
here is my code :

```html
import numpy as np 
import cv,cv2 
import cPickle as pickle 

#cap for capturing the video 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
f=open('videorecord.pkl', 'w')
vidrec = []
while(True): 
 #capture a frame from camera
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    # declare a list that will contain the frames 
    if ret==True:
 cv2.imshow('Streaming a Video',frame) 
 #encode each frame
        ret , frame1 = cv2.imencode('.jpeg' , frame)
        # append it to the list
        vidrec.append(frame1)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break 
    else: 
        break 
# add the list to the pkl file ...  
pickle.dump(vidrec ,f , pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# realse everything
cap.release() 
f.close() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

please can any one help me?

Comment: Everything in a computer is in binary.

Comment: when i printed to see whether it is binary with this `print(frame1)` here is the result in the terminal :  
[[255]
 [216]
 [255]
 ..., 
 [143]
 [255]
 [217]]
[[255]
 [216]
 [255]
 ..., 
 [ 63]
 [255]
 [217]]

Comment: This is just a basic binary-processing problem and python is not the best language for that. Look for binary-processing libs like bitstring and co. or even use numpy. (maybe even python's IO lib can be used). Apart from that i don'T think it's a good idea. As JPEGs will look like random-data (because of entropy-encoding) two consecutive frame will look like two random-frames too.